# Embedded site on Android checking does site is open by Application or Browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I build a new website then i build a new application for Android and embedded my site it into the application.

With the script below, I can understand that the user is entering to the site by mobile or desktop.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
 if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].innerHTML = 'html';
 }
}, false);
```

I want mobile users to download the app. With the script above i am forming html that gives link to mobile user to install my app.

Problem is that inserted html is shown by application at the same time.

How can i detect when the site is open by application ?

Answer (score 0):

To detect whether the site is being opened by a browser or the Android application use one of the following methods.

**1st Method**

Use server side coding to check for a request header.

*PHP:*

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "your.android.app.package.name") {
    //webview
} else {
    //browser
}
```

*JSP:*

```
if ("your.android.app.package.name".equals(req.getHeader("X-Requested-With")) ){
    //webview
} else {
    //browser
}
```

**2nd Method**

Bind javascript code to android code and call it.

Use the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation on any method that you want available to your JavaScript.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void runningOnAndroid() {
androidApp = true;
}
```

You can find the details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)